# Need to click twice for a function on <li> tag to fire

Tags: angular, angular5

I have the following snippet in my HTML. 
It works, but requires "**two clicks**" for the *selectCompany($event, company)* to fire for some reason.
How should I change the following, so the function works with only single clicking?

```
   <div class="row" *ngIf="companies.length > 0">
       <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div>
            <ul>
                <li class="" *ngFor="let company of companies; let index = index" (click)="selectCompany($event, company)">{{company.companyName}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

[Update]
The full snippet looks something like the following.
What I am trying to do is display a list of companies (asynchronously fetched from the server) as an user types in. 
When one of the companies is selected, it will be displayed as a label.
The problem I am facing is that the input text field keeps focused(active) when a company is selected for the first time, so two clicking is required.

```
<div id="custom-search" class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="company name" (keyup)="search($event)" (change)="search($event)">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label>Selected: <b>{{selectedCompanyName}}</b></label>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" *ngIf="companies.length > 0">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="auto-complete">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let company of companies; let index = index" (click)="selectCompany($event, company)">{{company.companyName}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me with one click. (only made selectCompany console.log arguments)

Comment: It's very likely this is an issue with `selectCompany()`, not with the template. This needs more context.

Comment: This is maybe caused by the $event param

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The problem seems that the third div is not set "active" when the <li> tag is clicked. I do not know how I can make sure it gets active before clicked...

Comment: What does "active" mean? Please try to create a reproduction in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I though It would be better to explain in text, so I have added more details to the original post. Am I clearer now?

Comment: I don't think text is helpful. This is unexpected behavior and without a proper way to investigate it's difficult to track down what might cause it.